# how to attach value to listbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having an issue where if they type in a new Person, then select "M" or "F" from the dropdown, in the listbox, I want both to show resulting to "John Doe M" with the example code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <%= Html.ListBox("personList")%> 
</div>

<%= Html.TextBox("newPerson")%>&nbsp;
     <select name="personInfo">
          <option value="Male">M</option>
          <option value="Female">F</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: this question is not clear, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Do you want this done client-side or server-side?  If the latter, then it's up to you to concatenate the string when you're populating the items for your Html.ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have almost no idea what you are asking, but I'm bored and a glutton for punishment so I tried. Are you trying to do something like the following -

http://jsfiddle.net/k3BrN/